# Differing left and right axis labels in psplot

Tags: pstricks, labels, pst-plot

This question is related to [psgraph with y-axis on left and right of graph and axis labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80062/psgraph-with-y-axis-on-left-and-right-of-graph-and-axis-labels) but can stand alone, as it is really about loops and variables.

I'm really sad that I have to ask this question, I am clearly incompetent.

In the following code can I replace the set of 13 consecutive `\rput` commands (near to the bottom) with `\multido{...}`?

The objective is to have a different scale on the right axis to that on the left. I have managed this, but the code is so inelegant there must be a proper way. It seems like you ought to be able to `\def\anumber{lowest y axis value string }` and then do some simple arithmetic on it inside a `\multido` to place the desired text in the desired locations.

```
\begin{pspicture}(1.2,1)

\readdata{\vin}{largesignalvin.txt}
\readdata{\vout}{largesignalvout.txt}
\readdata{\idone}{largesignalID1.txt}
\readdata{\idtwo}{largesignalID2.txt}

\psset{llx=-1cm,lly=-1cm}

\psset{xAxisLabel={Time [ms]}, xAxisLabelPos={c,-0.3in}, yAxisLabel={Voltage [V]}, yAxisLabelPos={-0.3in,c}}

\begin{psgraph}[axesstyle=axes, xticksize=0 12, yticksize=0 5, subticks=0, Dx=0.5, Oy=-6](0,-6)(5,6){7cm}{5cm}

\pstScalePoints(1e3,1e0){}{}

\listplot[linecolor=blue,linewidth=2pt]{\vin}
\listplot[linecolor=black,linewidth=2pt]{\vout}

\rput[r](5.58,-6){$-1.2$}
\rput[r](5.58,-5){$-1.0$}
\rput[r](5.58,-4){$-0.8$}
\rput[r](5.58,-3){$-0.6$}
\rput[r](5.58,-2){$-0.4$}
\rput[r](5.58,-1){$0.2$}
\rput[r](5.58,-0){$0.0$}
\rput[r](5.58,1){$0.2$}
\rput[r](5.58,2){$0.4$}
\rput[r](5.58,3){$0.6$}
\rput[r](5.58,4){$0.8$}
\rput[r](5.58,5){$1.0$}
\rput[r](5.58,6){$1.2$}

\rput{90}(5.85,0){Current[$\mu$A]}

\pstScalePoints(1e3,5e3){}{}
\listplot[linecolor=red,linewidth=2pt]{\idone}
\listplot[linecolor=green,linewidth=2pt]{\idtwo}

\end{psgraph}

\end{pspicture}
```

The data files, should they be needed, are available from http://www.iceamplifiers.co.uk/latex/[insert_name_of_file].txt

Answer (score 5):

no need for  `\multido`. Use a second axis:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}

\readdata{\vin}{largesignalvin.txt}
\readdata{\vout}{largesignalvout.txt}
\readdata{\idone}{largesignalID1.txt}
\readdata{\idtwo}{largesignalID2.txt}

\psset{llx=-1cm,lly=-1cm,
  xAxisLabel={Time [ms]}, xAxisLabelPos={c,-0.3in}, 
  yAxisLabel={Voltage [V]}, yAxisLabelPos={-0.3in,c}}

\begin{psgraph}[axesstyle=axes,xticksize=0 12,yticksize=0 5,subticks=0,Dx=0.5,Oy=-6](0,-6)(5,6){7cm}{5cm}
\pstScalePoints(1e3,1e0){}{}
\psaxes[xAxis=false,Dy=0.2,dy=1,ticks=none,axesstyle=none](5.9,0)(5.9,-6)(5.9,6)
\listplot[linecolor=blue,linewidth=2pt]{\vin}
\listplot[linecolor=black,linewidth=2pt]{\vout}
\rput{90}(5.9,0){Current[$\mu$A]}

\pstScalePoints(1e3,5e3){}{}
\listplot[linecolor=red,linewidth=2pt]{\idone}
\listplot[linecolor=green,linewidth=2pt]{\idtwo}

\end{psgraph}

\end{document}
```

[image]